# Codeigniter site loads on desktop, not mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile

I'm new to codeigniter and MVC's in general. I have a site that has been functioning fine for the past few months however after setting up a mobile version of it, I realized that the site fails to load on mobile devices. I get an error message that says "Unable to load the requested file: mobile.php"

The same issue occurs for the desktop version of the site where I use a file called default.php. As far as I can remember, the desktop version originally loaded on mobile. The only changes I made was added a few new files to the views in a new directory called mobile and set up a new controller. I tested loading the desktop and mobile version on 2 separate desktops so I don't think there's a caching issue going on. I can't think of any reason why this will load on a computer but not a phone.

Here's my controller.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mobile extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('template');
}
public function index(){    
    $this->template
        ->set_layout('mobile.php')
        ->title('T.E.B')
        ->build('mobile/index.php');
}
}
```

EDIT::

I took a look at the routes.php files and added another line for mobile but that hasn't changed anything.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['mobile/(:any)'] = 'mobile';
```

Comment: Try Checking the routes.php config ensure that when browsing from a mobile you are getting the URL you would expect if not try adding a default route into the config

Comment: How can I tell if the routes.php file has any errors? I updated my code above to include the routes.php contents

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for some reason changing the controller's name to anything other than mobile along with the directory for the views fixed everything

Comment: I feel your pain I have an issue with CI routing when using https:// - if you find anything please post back.